# Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Show that $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ has no solutions.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Show that $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ has no solutions.

I noticed that this is equivalent to proving $x^2\equiv 2(2k+1) \pmod p$. 
I also know that $x^2 \neq 2(2k+1)$. But I still can't prove it. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an $x$ such that $x^2=-1\pmod p$ then ${\rm ord}_p(x)=4$. Thus $4$ must divide the order of the multiplicative group modulo $p$ which is $p-1$.

Comment: Funny, haven't seen this before!

Comment: This is a standard argument :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What happens if you raise both sides to the power $\frac{p-1}2$ in the congruence $x^2\equiv-1$?

Comment: I wouldn't have come up with this neither, so don't worry. It's just a trick.

Comment: Perhaps a clever trick when it was first used, but from a group-theoretic point of view structurally very natural.

Comment: How so? Is there a better reason than "raising to the $\frac{p-1}2$th power will limit the possible residues"? I'm curious.

Comment: The order of an element divides the order of the group. For an odd prime $p$, any square root of $-1$ has order $4$. But $4$ does not divide $p-1$ in the case $p=4k+3$. The idea generalizes to $q$-th roots of $1$.

Comment: If I understand well, what you mean is by raising to the $\frac{p-1}2$th power, only elements of order $\leq2$ will give $1$ and so this is actually a disguised form of Omran's answer. Hadn't tought about it this way!